# Passing a variable into a DROP INDEX statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I just signed up and hope this makes sense.

Anyway, in short, I want to test if a certain column has an index and if so, drop the index. I want to find out if I can do that by *passing* the index name to a DROP INDEX statement.

Firstly, FYI the table name is 'Account' and the column name is 'ID'.

To test if the index exists I use the following (don't think I'm any sort of a genius, I got the SELECT statement from here):
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e183be6c-1177-4f81-b130-aeeeff7638fe/how-do-you-check-if-an-index-exists-for-sql-table-column

```
IF EXISTS 
(SELECT 
    sysindex.name AS IndexName
FROM 
    sys.indexes AS SysIndex
    INNER JOIN sys.index_columns AS SysIndexCol ON SysIndex.object_id = SysIndexCol.object_id AND SysIndex.index_id = SysIndexCol.index_id 
    INNER JOIN sys.columns AS SysCols ON SysIndexCol.column_id = SysCols.column_id AND SysIndexCol.object_id = SysCols.object_id 
WHERE 
   type <> 0 
   AND SysIndex.object_id in (Select systbl.object_id from sys.tables as systbl
   WHERE SysTbl.name = 'Account')
   AND SysCols.name = 'ID')

DROP INDEX dbo.Account.Account$ID;
GO
```

In the DROP INDEX statement above I have hard coded the index name ('Account$ID') - if you run the SELECT statement on its own it reveals the name, but it was also easily identifiable through SSMS anyway. *But*, rather than hard code the index name, I want to be able to somehow pass the index name (which is, as I said, revealed by the SELECT statement) to the DROP INDEX statement. I imagine it would be done by declaring a variable and somehow setting it to the query result, but I don't know how to do that. Can it be done?

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like that. Note the table name was set to a variable.

```
DECLARE @index_name NVARCHAR(MAX), @table_name NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @table_name = 'Account'  -- your table name

SELECT TOP 1
    @index_name = sysindex.name
FROM 
    sys.indexes AS SysIndex
    INNER JOIN sys.index_columns AS SysIndexCol ON SysIndex.object_id = SysIndexCol.object_id AND SysIndex.index_id = SysIndexCol.index_id 
    INNER JOIN sys.columns AS SysCols ON SysIndexCol.column_id = SysCols.column_id AND SysIndexCol.object_id = SysCols.object_id 
WHERE 
   type <> 0 
   AND SysIndex.object_id in (Select systbl.object_id from sys.tables as systbl
   WHERE SysTbl.name = @table_name)
   AND SysCols.name = 'id'

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'DROP INDEX dbo.' + @table_name + '.' + @index_name

IF @index_name IS NOT NULL
    exec sp_executesql @sql
```

**EDIT**

I added `TOP 1` to the query above as it may return more than one index.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @index_name SYSNAME
    ,   @table_name SYSNAME = 'dbo.Account'
    ,   @column_name SYSNAME = 'ID'

SELECT @index_name = i.name
FROM sys.indexes i
JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON i.[object_id] = ic.[object_id] 
    AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
WHERE i.[type] > 0
    AND i.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@table_name)
    AND COL_NAME(i.[object_id], ic.column_id) = @column_name

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'DROP INDEX ' + @table_name + '.' + @index_name
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```